# Node.JS, NPM: EJS deleted itself, installs (but doesn't install), and isn't available to Download?

Tags: npm, ejs

About 10 minutes ago I was following an online tutorial. I shut down the local server to bring my dog inside the house, then came back to the computer to finish the tutorial.

I restarted the server and got this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'

I looked in my **node_modules** folder, and I don't see "ejs" anywhere. I thought ok, no biggie, just reinstall. So I typed: `npm install ejs -g` into the terminal.

The terminal says:

```
+ ejs@2.6.1
updated 1 package in 0.275s
```

I looked in the node_modules folder again, and the "ejs" folder is not there. I checked the **package.json** file, and I don't see ejs listed under dependencies. (Actually, I don't know if it was there before, I can't remember. I think Express was the only Dependency)

I went to the EJS website (http://www.embeddedjs.com/) to see if I could download it directly, and just pop in the file directly onto my computer, but all of the download links return a 404 page.

There is another link at the top of their webpage: **Google Code**. I'm not sure which files I should download from there. I literally started tinkering with Node.js this morning.

I'm just super confused on why this is happening or how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed it globally. You can run npm list -g to see where global libraries are installed. You won't be able to find it in local directory where package.json is located.

Comment: awesome! That was it, thank you! 
One of the other things was installed globally in the tutorial, and I guess I read misread the directions.